# How to create a refreshable table using in-memory data in Flink for joins?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a Flink application that I rely on Table API. I do have a Kafka topic that I create a table. Then, we maintain an S3 object for list of IP addressed and some metadata information.

We also want to create a table on this S3 object. S3 object path is static and does not change, but I can override the S3 object and I want to refresh this table with the new data.

Basically, I have a collection in-memory read from the S3 object. How can I create a table and do join on the Kafka table most efficiently? The table should be refreshed when there is an update in S3 object.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Table that is backed by the S3 object, using the [FileSystem SQL Connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/filesystem.html), it might do what you are looking for. Note, however, that file system sources are not fully developed, and you may run into limitations that affect your use case.

You could instead use `StreamExecutionEnvironment#readFile` ([docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sources)), and convert the `DataStream` that it produces into a Table. Note that if you read a file with `readFile` while using `FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY` mode, and then modify the file, the entire file will be re-ingested.

Comment: Isn't the connector expecting a directory(prefix)instead of an object path?

Comment: I'm not sure; I know the filesystem SQL sink works that way. I've expanded my answer to include an alternative.

Comment: Thank you, I guess `PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY` would work. If I don't misunderstand, it will monitor the file and will re-ingest. I hope it will drop the existing content when new file comes, and do this atomically.

Comment: No, it won't happen atomically.

Comment: Do you think I can use the concept of `Temporal Tables`. For example, something similar to Hive Temporal Tabel(https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/hive/hive_streaming.html#hive-table-as-temporal-tables). My data volume is relatively small, I just need a proper abstraction that I can refresh my metadata and provide an SQL interface for joins

Comment: Flink has temporal tables (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/temporal_tables.html), and yes, I think that can be part of a solution. But if you need to update the entire table as one atomic transaction, that will be an interesting challenge.

Comment: @DavidAnderson is `PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY` supported by pyflink?